# Unable to determine what the withEnv is doing in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have just started writing Jenkinsfile. I was viewing the following two URLs to learn how to build a Java application, push it to Nexus and then invoke Ansible to deploy.

[Redhat Jenkinsfile description](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/integrating-ansible-jenkins-cicd-process)

[Actual Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/ricardozanini/soccer-stats/blob/master/Jenkinsfile)

In the second link the following is mentioned several times whose function I am unable to understand:

```
withEnv(["PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'm3'}/bin"])
```

What I can find from net is that `withEnv` is used to create/override a environment variables. But what is `${tool 'm3'}/bin` doing? Normally the syntax of `withEnv` is `VARIABLE_NAME=value/expression`.

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_double_quoted_string

Answer (score 1):

The `${}` is substituting a command/variable into the GString. See groovy docs on string Interpolation
From the looks of it, it would be safe to assume `tool 'm3'` is returning the install path which then gets /bin appended.

So the end result would be

`PATH+MAVEN=/my/path/to/m3/etc/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @metalisticpain's answer, there's some background configuration to the [tools directive](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools) on the Jenkins server itself that configures the installation paths to be used.

Let's say you have `jdk-1.8.0` installed as a tool name on the Jenkins server, then it can be used in the Jenkinsfile as such in your example:

```
withEnv(["PATH+JDK=${tool 'jdk-1.8.0'}/bin"])
```

Taken from the documentation linked above:

> The tool name must be pre-configured in Jenkins under Manage Jenkins → Global Tool → Configuration.